# Delete the blue border around a treeview in javafx via css

Tags: css, javafx, treeview

I would like to delete the [blue border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8wIp.jpg) around my treeview in JavaFX i already tried these settings:

```
#treev .expanded .tree-cell{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -fx-font-size: 11pt;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-background-insets: null;
    -fx-border-style: none;
    -fx-focus-color: black;
    }

#treev .tree-cell{
    -fx-background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: try with `-fx-background-insets:0;`

Comment: nah :/ doesn't work

Comment: Where did you put the property ? And `.expanded` is false it is a pseudo-class not a selector it's used like this `:expanded` !

Comment: What do you mean with "Where did you put the property ?"
:expanded did not work either